# How do I install gnotime in Ubuntu 15.10 and newer?

Tags: software-installation

The time tracker application `gnotime` was available in Ubuntu 15.04 ([here on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/gnotime)). However, Ubuntu releases from 15.10 to 17.10 does not contain any release, [just the source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/gnotime).

How can I still install gnotime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For Ubuntu 17.10: Compile it yourself

Installing the Ubuntu 15.04 packages will not work here, so we have to compile the program ourselves. This is possible, but has become a bit difficult as we deal with quite old software on a recent distribution. Here's how I succeeded:

#### 1. Install required build tools

1. `sudo apt install checkinstall`
2. Install `dbus-binding-tool`, later needed when compiling `gnotime`:

   `sudo apt install libdbus-glib-1-dev`

#### 2. Compile and install qof

Ubuntu 17.10 provides `libqof2`, but we need the earlier version. So we compile it from the unchanged 0.8.7 source package that was used for the Ubuntu 15.04 package:

1. `sudo apt-install sqlite libsqlite0-dev`
2. `mkdir qof && cd qof`
3. `wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/qof_0.8.7.orig.tar.gz`
4. `tar -xzf qof_0.8.7.orig.tar.gz && cd qof-0.8.7`
5. `./configure`
6. `make`
7. `sudo checkinstall make install`

#### 3. Compile and install gtkhtml 3.xx

Ubtuntu 17.10 provides gtkhtml version 4, but we need version 3. We compile version 3.32.2 from source, using the [package and patches](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/gtkhtml3.14) as provided by the Debian maintainers. Without these patches, compiling would not work.

1. `sudo apt install libenchant-dev`
2. `mkdir gtkhtml && cd gtkhtml`
3. `wget http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/g/gtkhtml3.14/gtkhtml3.14_3.32.2.orig.tar.gz`
4. `tar -xzf gtkhtml3.14_3.32.2.orig.tar.gz && cd gtkhtml-3.32.2`
5. Apply the patches provided by the Debian maintainers (I follow [these instructions](http://cs-people.bu.edu/doucette/xia/guides/debian-patch.txt)):

   1. `wget http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/g/gtkhtml3.14/gtkhtml3.14_3.32.2-2.2.debian.tar.gz`
   2. `tar -xzf gtkhtml3.14_3.32.2-2.2.debian.tar.gz` (it is important that this creates the `debian` subdirectory inside the normal `gtkhtml` source directory we created above)
   3. `apt-get install quilt`
   4. `export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches`
   5. `quilt push -a`
6. Replace all occurrences of `G_CONST_RETURN` in the source files with `const`. This backports [a fix](http://www.mirrorservice.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gtkhtml/4.1/gtkhtml-4.1.2.news) for [a bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=652154) provided in a later version that otherwise would prohibit compiling.
7. `./configure`
8. In `src/Makefile` in line 580 for target `gnotime`, append "-lm" to the line. This fixes an error "undefined reference to symbol 'lround@@GLIBC_2.2.5" according to [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006618). The cleaner solution is to include it as an option to `./configure` of course.
9. `make`
10. `sudo checkinstall make install`

#### 4. Compile and install gnotime

1. We use the (so far) most recent commit version `2e3181c`, so we get that as a snapshot first:

   `wget https://sourceforge.net/code-snapshots/git/g/gt/gttr/code.git/gttr-code-2e3181c7b16cc95b2ca50a94bf8d23453fb561a5.zip`
2. Install the remaining build dependencies that we did not have to compile ourselves:

   `sudo apt install gnome-common libglib2.0-dev guile-2.0-dev gtk+-2.0 libgtk2.0-dev libgnome2-dev libgnomeui-dev libglade2-dev libxss-dev`
3. `./autogen.sh`
4. `make`
5. `sudo checkinstall make install`
6. Now start `gnotime` with: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib; gnotime` or make this library path change permanent using [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67783).

### For Ubuntu 15.10: Install the 15.04 packages

While not the cleanest solution, you can still successfully install the Ubuntu 15.04 package and its dependencies manually. Example commands for AMD64 architecture:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/188278296/qof-data_0.8.8-1_all.deb;
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/188278297/libqof2_0.8.8-1_amd64.deb;
wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/160508015/libgtkhtml3.14-19_3.32.2-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb;
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/188196809/gnotime_2.4.1-1_amd64.deb;

sudo dpkg -i qof-data_0.8.8-1_all.deb;
sudo dpkg -i libqof2_0.8.8-1_amd64.deb;
sudo dpkg -i libgtkhtml3.14-19_3.32.2-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb;
sudo dpkg -i gnotime_2.4.1-1_amd64.deb;
```

With this method, there will be no automatic updates, but updates are not expectable for gnotime anyway, at the moment.

(A better method would be using version pinning or installation from [the source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/gnotime).)

Comment: You could add some instructions to compile the package.